# Is there an approximate substitute for a Torx T40 bit?

Tags: bolts, bits

I needed a Torx T40 bit for a job, but that bit was missing from my toolbox.

I didn't want to strip the bolts (they were fastened tightly over a decade ago), so I had to wait until I could get the exact bit.

Is there an approximate substitute for a Torx T40 bit that I could have used?

Comment: Were you hoping to re-use the bolt? If not, you could have ground/cut a slot across the head and used a plain old slot screwdriver. (This tends to be handy for stripped/security screws.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I did need to reuse to the bolt.  But if I didn't, that would have worked!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many you have and what is at risk ... could fit the T40 screw head socket with the largest possible hex/allen bit, spray the T40 recess with silicone, clean the hex bit, dab some quick curing epoxy or liquid metal into the recess, immediately followed by inserting the bit (only) until cured.

Comment: Interesting, but you'll never again be able to use a T40 bit in that bolt...

Comment: I think he means to use the silicone as a release agent.  It's more the allen bit that would be headed for the scrap.  Although epoxy does not like heat, so it may be possible to melt off the epoxy before annealing the steel.